# SQLAlchemy Model Django like Save Method?

Tags: django, django-models, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy for a project. However, I am more accustomed to Django's ORM.

I would like to know if, in the sqlachemy ORM, there is anything similar to a Django models' save() method that I can overrride to implement actions automatically upon a 'commit' / 'save.'

Answer (score 34):

You can extend your models with some simple crud methods to achieve something similar to Django ORM / ActiveRecord:

```
# SQLAlchemy db_session setup omitted
...

Model = declarative_base(name='Model')
Model.query = db_session.query_property()

class CRUD():

     def save(self):
         if self.id == None:
             db_session.add(self)
         return db_session.commit()

      def destroy(self):
          db_session.delete(self)
          return db_session.commit()

class User(Model, CRUD):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, email):
        self.email = email
```

You can then save or destroy the model as needed:

```
user = User('example@example.com')
user.save()
```

Comment: What does the session setup look like? Do you setup a session and then import that into each model? In other words do you have 1 session for each app instance or multiple?

Answer (score 5):

Probably, you are looking for [ORM events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#orm-events).

Take a look at [instance events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#instance-events) and [session events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#session-events).

Answer (score 4):

Good news for you!

I created package for that. It implements Active Record pattern for SQLAlchemy.

**See https://github.com/absent1706/sqlalchemy-mixins#active-record**

It also has many very useful features such as Django [lookups that span relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), declarative eager load and readable `print` for SQAlchemy.

Comment: great idea. CRUD with SQLAlchemy raw is a nightmare!

Answer (score -2):

You can try Flask Diamond. It is similar with Django.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).