# Is there a canonical way of implementing CRUD on top of SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, crud, semantics

I've worked on a variety of SQLAlchemy projects over the past few years, but this has meant that CRUD has been done in different ways:

- In many cases, the module where a declarative model is defined would include functions (read: not model methods; just module-level functions) to which CRUD is delegated, e.g.:

  ```
  class Foo(Base):
      bar = Column(String)


  def create_foo(bar):
      with Session() as sess:
          try:
              sess.add(Foo(bar=bar))
              return sess.commit()
          except IntegrityError:
              sess.rollback()
              raise

  # ... and so on...
  ```

  These are basically the query API calls from SQLAlchemy's docs, wrapped in some session management code and delegated to functions.

  The obvious disadvantages here are a large amount of overhead just to define a single model's CRUD, a large amount of code *duplication* especially if you have many models, and a lack of elegance, especially in exception handling.
- In some cases, I've seen decorators implemented for some CRUD operations:

  ```
  from contextlib import contextmanager

  @contextmanager
  def session_scope():
      """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
      session = Session()
      try:
          yield session
          session.commit()
      except:
          session.rollback()
          raise
      finally:
          session.close()


  def safe_session(func):
      with session_scope() as sess:
          def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
              func(sess, *args, **kwargs)


  @safe_session
  def create_foo(session, bar):
      session.add(Foo(bar=bar))
  ```

  And while this works fairly consistently (in terms of flexibility and stability), I haven't seen it implemented very often, so I'm cautious about using this in code bases where it may come off as "weird" or "nonstandard."
- Finally, there's [another question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584974/sqlalchemy-model-django-like-save-method) that shows how to use multiple inheritance with a `CRUD` superclass in addition to the `declarative_base()`-generated class to implement semantics similar to Django and Rails's ActiveRecord pattern:

  ```
  # SQLAlchemy db_session setup omitted
  ...

  Model = declarative_base(name='Model')
  Model.query = db_session.query_property()

  class CRUD():
      def save(self):
          if self.id == None:
              db_session.add(self)
          return db_session.commit()

      def destroy(self):
          db_session.delete(self)
          return db_session.commit()

  class User(Model, CRUD):
      __tablename__ = 'users'
      id = db.Column(db.integer, primary_key=True)
      email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

      def __init__(self, email):
          self.email = email
  ```

  ... But this is obscure at best, and leaves class definition semantics a bit awkward, with potentially a bunch of error handling in the constructor.

With these three "major" methods of performing CRUD on SQLAlchemy (and probably a number of others available and unlisted here), which is the most semantically correct?

Is there some other, more semantically-correct (or even canonical) way to perform CRUD that isn't listed here?

Comment: You should read http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it. Handling the session's lifetime in a factory function/method of a single entity is a bit of an antipattern. What if you want to `create_foo` as a part of a larger transaction?

Comment: This is a good point, and definitely worth mentioning — it still leaves the original question open, though. I'll incorporate it into the example.

Comment: since sqlalchemy is an implementation of the data mapper pattern and not active record, its seems reasonable to keep the session and mapped classes separate. iow, neither of the options you propose